# Mapping project-name and application-id in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, deployment, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy my project on the appengine. I use maven to build it. Name of my project (say, `project-name`)and the `application-id` on the appengine are different. Is there a way to map the application-id with my project? Every time I say,

```
mvn appengine:update
```

I get an error message like

```
This application does not exist (app_id='project-name').
```

Since I have not said which application-id to map it with, it attempts to find an application-id same as y project name. How should I fix this?

Comment: Did the answer help you to solve your issue? Is it working now?

Comment: If you do not see `appengine-aplication.xml`, you probably do not use modules. In such a case it should be enough to set app's ID in appengine-web.xml. What exactly do you mean by project name?

Comment: @pgiecek Your answer is perfect. I will update the comment on the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appengine-application.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` files contain general information used by App Engine tools when your app is deployed. Put your application ID (the ID you registered when you created your application in the Google Developers Console) into `<application>` element.

appengine-application.xml

```
<appengine-application xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>your-application-id</application>
</appengine-application>
```

appengine-web.xml

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>your-application-id</application>
  <module>default</module>
  <version>v1</version>
  ...
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Perfect! Changing the name of the application in appengine-application.xml inside the ear module did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

All the App Engine Configuration information is  store in the appengine-web.xml  You  must need to update them as per your  google app engine project information.

**For example my**

**project id  :** prabhatabc-2012

& i want to run my application on the  **version : v2**

so i need to update  my **appengine-web.xml** file project id(**prabhatabc-2012**) in `<application></application>` and  version in  `<version>`**v2**`</version>`

```
 <application>prabhatabc-2012</application>
  <version>v2</version>
```